# Play sound with delay (100ms)?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

What is the best way to play sound with delay 50ms or 100ms?
Here is something, what i tried:

```
var beat = new Audio('/sound/BEAT.wav');
var time = 300;
playbeats();
function playbeats(){
  beat.cloneNode().play();
  setTimeout(playbeats, time);
}
```

This is working correctly but my goal is to play BEAT.wav after every 100ms. When I change "time" variable to 100, then it is so "laggy".
721ms is my BEAT.wav (that's why im using cloneNode())

What is alternatives to solve this?

Comment: What do you mean by _"laggy"_?

Comment: How long does your BEAT.wav last? Could you share a link to it?

Comment: It need to play sound every time after 100ms (when i set timeout arg 2 to 100 ), but there is about 30ms - 100ms between beats.

Comment: What is purpose of calling `.cloneNode()`? Are you trying to loop audio? Could you use `loop` property of `<audio>`?

Comment: If you this kind of accuracy consider using Web Audio API instead. Audio does not guarantee that the sample will plat in an instance due to various factors.

Answer (score 1):

You can use setInterval(), the arguments are the same.

```
setInterval(function() {
  playbeats();
 }, 100);
```

and your function playbeats function should be.

```
function playbeats(){
var tempBeat=beat.cloneNode();
 tempBeat.play();
```

}

your whole program should be like this.

```
var beat = new Audio('/sound/BEAT.wav');
  setInterval(function() {
  playbeats();
  }, 100);

 function playbeats(){
 var tempBeat=beat.cloneNode();
 tempBeat.play();

  }
```

Comment: What is purpose of using `.cloneNode()`?

Comment: The cloneNode() method creates a copy of a node, and returns the clone.

Comment: Yes, though why is using `.cloneNode()` necessary to return expected result of looping audio playback?

Comment: Yes, I agree this is not necessary. I will edit my answer.

Comment: So you can set your delay (721+100) setInterval method.

Comment: This would be a solution, but not for me. 721ms is my BEAT.wav file length, but i need to play it after every 100ms. That's because why i trying to use .cloneNode() too

Comment: So you can again add .cloneNode() I thought once the audio is finished then you have to wait for 100 ms. I will edit my answer.

Comment: yes. So, it's working too, but one time is `~60ms - 80ms between two BEAT.wav, another time 100ms (like i need). That was my problem too. SetInterval and setTimeout (when looping) working 100% correctly when i set time 300ms +. But no luck, when i trying to looping it after every 100ms

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Web Audio API but the code will be a bit different.If you want the Web Audio API's timing and loop capabillities you will need to load the file into a buffer first. It also requires that your code is run on a server. Here is an example:

```
var audioContext = new AudioContext();
var audioBuffer;
var getSound = new XMLHttpRequest();
getSound.open("get", "sound/BEAT.wav", true);
getSound.responseType = "arraybuffer";

getSound.onload = function() {
    audioContext.decodeAudioData(getSound.response, function(buffer) {
        audioBuffer = buffer;
    });
};

getSound.send();


function playback() {
    var playSound = audioContext.createBufferSource();
    playSound.buffer = audioBuffer;
    playSound.loop = true;
    playSound.connect(audioContext.destination);
    playSound.start(audioContext.currentTime, 0, 0.3);
}
window.addEventListener("mousedown", playback);
```

Comment: Is there alternatives too, when i need to do it on client side (When my code needs to run on client-side)?

Comment: The code runs client side its just it needs to be running off a server.....if that makes sense.

Comment: To clarify the audio files need to be referenced from a running server but the code itself is client side.

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend using the Web Audio API. From there, you can simply loop a buffer source node every 100ms or 50ms or whatever time you want. 
To do this, as stated in other responses, you'll need to use an XMLHttpRequest to load the sound file via a server

```
// set up the Web Audio context
var audioCtx = new AudioContext();

// create a new buffer 
// 2 channels, 4410 samples (100 ms at 44100 samples/sec), 44100 samples per sec 
var buffer = audioCtx.createBuffer(2, 4410, 44100);

// load the sound file via an XMLHttpRequest from a server 
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', '/sound/BEAT.wav', true);
request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

request.onload = function () {
   var audioData = request.response;

   audioCtx.decodeAudioData(audioData, function (newBuffer) { 
      buffer = newBuffer;
   });
}

request.send();
```

Now you can make a Buffer Source Node to loop the playback

```
// create the buffer source
var bufferSource = audioCtx.createBufferSource();

// set the buffer we want to use
bufferSource.buffer = buffer;

// set the buffer source node to loop
bufferSource.loop = true;

// specify the loop points in seconds (0.1s = 100ms)
// this is a little redundant since we already set our buffer to be 100ms
// so by default it would loop when the buffer comes to an end (at 100ms)
bufferSource.loopStart = 0;
bufferSource.loopEnd = 0.1;

// connect the buffer source to the Web Audio sound output
bufferSource.connect(audioCtx.destination);

// play!
bufferSource.start();
```

Note that if you stop the playback via `bufferSource.stop()`, you will not be able to start it again. You can only call `start()` once, so you'll need to create a new source node if you want to start playback again.

Note that because of the way the sound file is loaded via an `XMLHttpRequest`, if you try to test this on your machine without running a server, you'll get a cross-reference request error on most browsers. So the simplest way to get around this if you want to test this on your machine is to run a Python SimpleHTTPServer